# how to properly configure node middleware in a meteor application

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have installed multer middleware for use in my meteor app:

```
{
        "multer": "0.1.8"
}
```

I have meteorhack:npm also installed

Now, I'm trying to configure the middlware this way:

```
var multer = Meteor.npmRequire('multer');

Meteor.app
    .use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename+Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
        var fileName = file.name;
        var done=true;
    }
}));
```

When only the first line is present, I do not have any issues.

But, when I'm trying to actually configure the middleware, I get the following error:

```
W20150609-13:51:29.641(-5)? (STDERR)          
W20150609-13:51:29.641(-5)? (STDERR) /home/eugene/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150609-13:51:29.641(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150609-13:51:29.641(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150609-13:51:29.644(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'use' of undefined
W20150609-13:51:29.644(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/startup/loadMulter.js:4:6
W20150609-13:51:29.644(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/startup/loadMulter.js:18:3
W20150609-13:51:29.644(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/eugene/dev/meteor/socially/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150609-13:51:29.644(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150609-13:51:29.644(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/eugene/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150609-13:51:29.644(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/eugene/dev/meteor/socially/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
```

So, it appears, that the Meteor object has no property named "app".

In that case, what is the proper syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor uses `connect` to handle server-side routing and middlewares.

The [`webapp`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/webapp) package exposes a `WebApp` object that has a `connectHandlers` property on which you can add your own middlewares.

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(multer({
  dest: './uploads/',
  [...]
}));
```

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp